# Get a specific file with PnP Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, export, import

I need to get a **specific** file in the SitePages of a SharePoint Online site collection. I know how to get all pages with PnP (see code below), but I need only one specific.

**Export & Import of all sites:**

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url https://contoso.sharepoint.com
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -out template.xml -Handlers PageContents -IncludeAllClientSidePages
Connect-PnPOnline -url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/anothersite
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -path template.xml
```

I checked the .xml in Visual Studio and found elements like "PageName" and "Title" but I can't get it to work. Any ideas? I don't want to edit the complete export in Visual Studio and use that. I has to be easier right?

Comment: Did you mean to get a specific Site Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download a specific file, use the following syntax:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite
Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/somesite/SitePages/Home.aspx" -AsFile
```

The parameter `-AsFile` makes the command save the file to your current directory.

To upload the same file to another site collection, you would use the following:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/anothersite
Add-PnPFile -Path .\Home.aspx -Folder SitePages
```

Comment: Okay, I got that. Can you help me how to add this then to a new site collection?

Comment: I updated my answer to include upload

Comment: Thank you! I knew, it isn't that difficult.